# Text overflow flutter

Tags: flutter, text, containers, overflow, ellipsis

I have the next widget, which is rendered with overflow. I have tried to solve, but i don't know. Can anyone help me? The aim is to do a custom card inside listview.
I have tried to wrap with expanded buth then, the error is referenced with constraints.

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

     import '../../shared/AppTheme.dart';

     class ComandaScreen extends StatefulWidget {
      const ComandaScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

     @override
     State<ComandaScreen> createState() => _ComandaScreenState();
      }

      class _ComandaScreenState extends State<ComandaScreen> {
      bool expanded = false;
      int unidades = 0;

        final List<Map<String, dynamic>> _items = List.generate(
       10, (index) => {'id': index, 'Nombre': 'Nuggets $index', 
       'isExpanded': false, "unidades": 8});

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ButtonStyle flatButtonStyle = TextButton.styleFrom(
      shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4.0)),
      ),
    );

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Comanda'),
        backgroundColor: AppTheme.backgroundColor,
        foregroundColor: AppTheme.primaryTextColor,
        elevation: 0,
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: ExpansionPanelList(
          elevation: 3,
          // expandedHeaderPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
          expansionCallback: (index, isExpanded) {
            setState(() {
              _items[index]['isExpanded'] = !isExpanded;
            });
          },
          animationDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
          children: _items
              .map(
                (item) => ExpansionPanel(
                  canTapOnHeader: true,
                  // backgroundColor: item['isExpanded'] == true ? Colors.cyan[100] : Colors.white,
                  headerBuilder: (context, isExpanded) {
                    return Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      child: Row(children: [
                        const CircleAvatar(
                            child: Text(
                          '1',
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        )),
                        const SizedBox(
                          width: 10,
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              const Text(
                                'Nuggets',
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                              ),
                              Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                children: [
                                  Column(
                                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children: const [
                                      Text(
                                        'Unidades: ${7}',
                                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        'Pendientes: 400',
                                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                  const SizedBox(
                                    width: 20,
                                  ),
                                  Column(
                                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children: const [
                                      Text(
                                        'Precio: 10 €',
                                        maxLines: 1,
                                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        'Total: 70 €',
                                        maxLines: 1,
                                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ]),
                    );
                  },
                  body: ButtonBar(
                    alignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                    buttonHeight: 52.0,
                    buttonMinWidth: 90.0,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      TextButton(
                        style: flatButtonStyle,
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            item['unidades'] += 1;
                          });
                        },
                        child: Column(
                          children: const <Widget>[
                            Icon(
                              Icons.add,
                              color: AppTheme.grismedio,
                            ),
                            // Padding(
                            //   padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2.0),
                            // ),
                            // Text('Más'),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      TextButton(
                        style: flatButtonStyle,
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            item['unidades'] -= 1;
                          });
                        },
                        child: Column(
                          children: const <Widget>[
                            Icon(
                              Icons.remove,
                              color: AppTheme.grismedio,
                            ),
                            // Padding(
                            //   padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2.0),
                            // ),
                            // Text('Menos'),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      TextButton(
                        style: flatButtonStyle,
                        onPressed: () {},
                        child: Column(
                          children: const <Widget>[
                            Icon(
                              Icons.edit_outlined,
                              color: AppTheme.grismedio,
                            ),
                            // Padding(
                            //   padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2.0),
                            // ),
                            // Text('Editar'),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      TextButton(
                        style: flatButtonStyle,
                        onPressed: () {},
                        child: Column(
                          children: const <Widget>[
                            Icon(
                              Icons.delete_outline_outlined,
                              color: AppTheme.grismedio,
                            ),
                            // Padding(
                            //   padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2.0),
                            // ),
                            // Text('Eliminar'),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      TextButton(
                        style: flatButtonStyle,
                        onPressed: () {},
                        child: Column(
                          children: const <Widget>[
                            Icon(
                              Icons.card_giftcard_outlined,
                              color: AppTheme.grismedio,
                            ),
                            // Padding(
                            //   padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2.0),
                            // ),
                            // Text('Invitar'),
                          ],
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  isExpanded: item['isExpanded'],
                ),
              )
              .toList(),
          // Card_lineaComanda(flatButtonStyle),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I 've edited the code to show all screen widget.

Image of result of code before:
[image]

Comment: Are you providing the same code as in your image?

Comment: Yes ,  without the part of expanded panel, since the error is in the container, but i don't know where.

Comment: I don't get an overflow with your code. So please [edit] your question to provide that code as weell

Comment: okey, I edit the code to show al screen view.

Comment: what phone you are using to capture the screen?

Comment: im running on windows and resizing the screen

Comment: @JoseDavid See if my answer here helps:https://stackoverflow.com/a/72808524/12349734

Comment: JoseDavid as you said you are resizing the windows and as the error(not blocker one though) says overflow. So the size you provided for the widgets is not enough as you resize it, if you want to preserve the design check @MendelG comment or you can wrap the widgets with Wrap Widget instead of Row for certain texts

Comment: @Prabhakaran can you show me your code? thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

For desktop applications, you can prevent the resize with breakpoint, so the error won't happen. In the pubsec.yaml file, add the following dependency.

```
window_size:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding.git
      path: plugins/window_size
```

And in your main method before runapp add this code with min-width and min-height below which the app won't resize.

```
const double desktopMinWidth = 800.0;
const double desktopMinHeight = 600.0;

if (Platform.isMacOS || Platform.isWindows) {
    setWindowMinSize(const Size(desktopMinWidth, desktopMinHeight));
    setWindowMaxSize(Size.infinite);
}
```

Note: Once done restart your app.

For mobile, it is entirely a different case. You might need to restructure the design